# @import Issue in LESS

Tags: html, less

I am trying to import multiple .less files into a .less style sheet. The problem I have is that LESS recognizes only the 1st @import "style.less"; file and not the ones below it.which results in the page not loading properly and styless / fonts missing after Grunt compiles it. Below is the @import command I am using.

```
@import "global.less";
@import "fonts.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

Comment: What tool are you using to preprocess your less files? Your imports look ok.
http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature

Comment: I have setup Grunt

Comment: Can you run your less grunt task again adding `--verbose` to the end of it and check the output?

Comment: Thanks. will check and get back

Comment: Not sure where the issue is, though its getting compiled, its not reflecting in the browser.

Comment: what does the console say - when you run it with the verbose argument?

Comment: its not giving any error

Comment: In situations like this it's usually helpful to look at the compiled CSS file directly (i.e. open it in any text editor) just to make sure it's really your Less tool-chain issue (like you suspect) and not some browser glitch (caching, wrong link etc.).

Comment: just a quick idea on this. If you don't prefix the files with _ the files will be all rendered as separate CSS files. It might be, that therefore the imports can not be processed. But that depends on your tool configuration, as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I was out of town. I did manage to fix the issue. There was a tag that was not closed properly which was causing the problem.